# How to get all versions of a multi-line text field in a workflow

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, versioning, multiline-text-field

I have a custom list with versioning which contains a multi-line text field with append.
In any workflow (insert, update triggered...) i cannot read the content of that field (always blank) although i can see the field updated and the versions created.
How can i read the content of this field from the last version or any version in a workflow?
If we have a solution OOTB i would appreciate..

Nuno

Comment: Sounds like an unusual issue.  Have you tried exporting to list data to Excel?  I'm wondering whether it might show some text in Excel, even though SP doesn't display it.